# How to stop gecko-mediaplayer from buffering endlessly?

Tags: configuration, mplayer

I'm using the [gecko-mediaplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/maverick/gecko-mediaplayer) plugin (formerly "mplayerplug-in"). The totem plugin was not always working correctly with Opera, and I'm actually depending on the [Copy URL] feature of gecko-mediaplayer.

However that plugin does some inept buffering of videos. It seems to default to 20% caching regardless of what you set in the preferences window. This is quite annoying for big video files. But appearantly it's by design http://groups.google.com/group/gecko-mediaplayer/browse_thread/thread/b7f0f5a3cedc8979
The Gentoo forums listed some workaround http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-816690.html - but `~/.config/gecko-mediaplayer/gecko-mediaplayer.conf` is not working in the Ubuntu version.

Does anyone know the actual way to configure the cache= size. Which is the real configuration filename under Ubuntu?

---

I've now tried that gconf registry, but `apps > gecko-mediaplayer > preferenes > cache` has no effect either.

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the source code suggests that the gconf setting is called "cache_size" not "cache", and that the default value is 2048.

If all else fails you could always change it in the plugin source code and rebuild the package. It's on line 280 of src/plugin.cpp.

Comment: Interesting +1, but it has no effect. My 10.04 version of that plugin does not seem to contain `cache_size` as per `strings ../gecko-mediaplayer.so`. Which version did you check out? (I would like to avoid any manual compilations nowadays.)

Comment: I checked the 10.10 version - gecko-mediaplayer-0.9.9.2 Also, since it appears to use dbus to fetch the config you could monitor what it is really doing with 'dbus-monitor --session' or similar.

Comment: My compiled version also does not have the string "cache_size" - but it is right there in the source code...

Comment: Identical version. Some things might be compiled out(?) I'm going to check out the source now too.. `dbus-monitor` was interesting, but inconclusive (displayed the buffering, but no config fetching). Thanks so far for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the plugin takes its settings from `/apps/gnome-mplayer/preferences` (not from `gecko-mediaplayer`). You can try and change the settings there.

There is one problem though - it will only allow you to change the `cache_size` (overall size of the cache), not the `cache_min` (the percentage when it starts playing) key, which is probably more interesting for you.

Comment: Confusing, but yes, it seems to use both. The plugin corresponds to the `disable_*` settings in `gecko-mediaplayer`, but some of the other options turn up in `gnome-mplayer`. I'm looking into gconf/schemas/gnome-mplayer if there are other interesting options...